# Bulk upload / publish multiple power bi's from folder

Tags: powerbi, upload, multiple-file-upload

i found a way to download all .pbix files in one workspace via powershell. is there also way to publish multiple power bi files in to one workspace (all files will be stored in one folder)?

Thanks for any Help!

i found some ideas to do this via Power BI REST API - but didn't really understand it...

Answer (score 1):

You want the [New-PowerBIReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.reports/new-powerbireport?view=powerbi-ps) cmdlet, which "Loads a Power BI report from a pbix file and deploys it to the Power BI service."

Comment: Hi - Thank you!! i found a solution :) 
An additional question: is it possible via any programming language to change the dataset source? 
for upload and download i used powershell

Comment: Please ask additional questions in a new question.  And include details about the change you need.  Is it just a change in the connection string?  Something else?

Comment: Hi i add my question as a new one : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324827/upload-multiple-pbix-from-folder-into-workspace-with-a-new-dataset-source)