# Upload multiple pbix from folder into workspace with a new dataset source

Tags: powerbi

I downloaded multiple power bi's with the same datasource connection. Now i want to upload them into a new Workspace and connect them with the new dataset source id.
My current upload code in powershell uploads them into the new workspace but are still connected to the dataset in the "old" workspace...

Some brainstorm:

- First i would upload the dataset into the new workspace
- get the Dataset Id
- and last upload the pbix reports and define the dataset source with the new id

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?
Thank you!!

------- My upload code:

```
$workspaceName = "MyWorkspace"
$workspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name $workspaceName
$PBIFilePath = "My\Path\...\"

ForEach($ReportName in Get-ChildItem $PBIFilePath -Filter *.pbix)
{ 
    Write-Host "------ Uploading " $ReportName
    $FullPath = $PBIFilePath + $ReportName
    $import = New-PowerBIReport -Path $FullPath -Workspace $workspace -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrit
}
Write-Host "------------------Done------------------"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called "report rebind", see the [Reports - Rebind Report In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/rebind-report-in-group) API.

On the doc page there's a "Try it out" button where you can fill in a form and make the call.  In this case POST

```
{
    datasetId: "<datasetId>"
}
```

to

`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/<workspaceId>/reports/<reportId>/Rebind`

With headers

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...H66IKh8dfDA
Content-type: application/json
```

Comment: I am sorry but i dont understand the docu/function [Reports - Rebind Reports in Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/rebind-report-in-group)
Can you give me an example? 
'POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/reports/{reportId}/Rebind'